# RecyclerView Displays only last objects in List

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to display data in a `RecyclerView`. I have created an adapter to handle the `RecyclerView`s from different activities. The issue I am facing is displaying the data appropriately. So far I can only display the last elements in the list. In this case, the last candidate for each ContestedOffice. I have attached my code for both the activity and adapter as well as a screenshot of the output.

**My Adapter Class**

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String LOGCAT = RecyclerAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_VOTE = 0;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_PREVIEW = 1;
    private List candidatesList;
    private LinearLayout checkBoxParent;
    private VoteActivity voteActivity;
    private Context context;

    public RecyclerAdapter(List candidatesList) //Generic List
    {
        this.candidatesList = candidatesList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (candidatesList.get(position) instanceof Candidate) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_PREVIEW;
        } else {
            return VIEW_TYPE_VOTE;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();

        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_PREVIEW) {
            View preview = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_candidate_recycler, parent, false);
            return new CandidateViewHolder(preview); // view holder for candidates items
        } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_VOTE) {
            View ballot = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_ballot_view, parent, false); //false too
            return new BallotViewHolder(ballot); // view holder for ContestedOffice items
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final int itemType = getItemViewType(position);

        if (itemType == VIEW_TYPE_PREVIEW) {
            CandidateViewHolder.class.cast(holder).bindData((Candidate)
                    candidatesList.get(position));

        } else if (itemType == VIEW_TYPE_VOTE) {
            BallotViewHolder.class.cast(holder).bindData((ContestedOffice)
                    candidatesList.get(position));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.d(LOGCAT, " Size: " + candidatesList.size());
        return candidatesList.size();
    }

    /**
     * ViewHolder class
     */
    private class BallotViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private AppCompatTextView vote_candidate_name;
        private AppCompatTextView vote_candidate_details;
        private AppCompatTextView vote_candidate_party;
        BallotViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            checkBoxParent = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_layout_parent);
            vote_candidate_name = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vote_candidate_name)
            vote_candidate_party = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vote_candidate_party);
            vote_candidate_details = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vote_candidate_details);
        }

        void bindData(ContestedOffice candidate)
        {
            int length = candidate.getList().size();

            Log.d(LOGCAT, "BallotList size:" + length);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            //params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
            params.gravity = Gravity.END;

            CheckBox checkBox = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                vote_candidate_name.setText(candidate.getList().get(i).getCandidateName());
                vote_candidate_party.setText(candidate.getList().get(i).getParty());
                vote_candidate_details.setText(candidate.getList().get(i).getDetails());

                //Create checkboxes for each recycler view created
                checkBox = new CheckBox(context);
                checkBox.setTag(candidate.getList().get(i).getCandidateID());
                checkBox.setId(candidate.getList().get(i).getCandidateID());
                //checkBox.setText(R.string.checkBox_message);
                checkBox.setText(String.valueOf(candidate.getList().get(i).getCandidateID()));
                checkBox.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                Log.d(LOGCAT, "TAGS: " + checkBox.getTag() + " id: " + checkBox.getId());
            }
            if (checkBox != null) {
                checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
            checkBoxParent.addView(checkBox, params);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Is the view now checked?
            boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();

            // Check which checkbox was clicked
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case 31:
                    if (checked) {
                        Log.d(LOGCAT, "Here:" + v.getTag().toString());
                    } else

                        break;
                case 30:
                    if (checked) {
                        Log.d(LOGCAT, "Here:" + v.getTag().toString());
                    } else

                        break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * ViewHolder class
     */
    private class CandidateViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private AppCompatTextView candidate_name;
        private AppCompatTextView candidate_details;
        private AppCompatTextView candidate_party;
        private AppCompatTextView candidate_position;
        // private AppCompatImageView candidate_image;

        CandidateViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            candidate_name = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.candidate_name);
            //  candidate_image = (AppCompatImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.candidate_image);
            candidate_position = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.candidate_position);
            candidate_party = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.candidate_party);
            candidate_details = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.candidate_details);
        }

        void bindData(Candidate candidate)//Candidate
        {
            candidate_name.setText(candidate.getCandidateName());
            candidate_position.setText(candidate.getPosition());
            candidate_details.setText(candidate.getDetails());
            candidate_party.setText(candidate.getParty());
            // candidate_image.setImageBitmap(candidate.getCandidatePhoto());
        }

    }
}
```

**My VoteActivity Class**

```
public class VoteActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private static final String LOGCAT = VoteActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private AppCompatActivity activity = VoteActivity.this;

    private RecyclerView vote_recycler_view;
    private LinearLayout checkBoxParent;

    private CheckBox vote_candidate_checkBox;

    private AppCompatButton appCompatButtonVote;

    private RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    private Ballot ballot;

    private List <ContestedOffice> ballotList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Candidate> candidateList = new ArrayList<>();
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vote);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

        initViews();
        initObjects();
        initListeners();
    }

    private void initListeners()
    {
        appCompatButtonVote.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void initObjects()
    {
        recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(ballotList);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(activity);
        vote_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        vote_recycler_view.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        vote_recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);
        vote_recycler_view.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
        getCandidates();
    }

    private void getCandidates()
    {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
        {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
            {
                ballotList.clear();
                candidateList.clear();
                candidateList.addAll(databaseHelper.getAllCandidates());
                createBallot();
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                                    recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    private void initViews()
    {
        checkBoxParent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_layout_parent);
        vote_recycler_view = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.vote_recycler_view);
        //vote_candidate_checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.vote_candidate_checkBox);
        appCompatButtonVote = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.appCompatButtonVote);
    }

    public List<ContestedOffice> createBallot()
    {
        int candidateListSize = candidateList.size();
        String position;

        ArrayList<String> positionArray = new ArrayList<>();

        ContestedOffice office;

        //Looping through the candidates list and add all the positions being contested for
        // to an array list.
        for (int i = 0; i< candidateListSize; i++)
        {
            position = candidateList.get(i).getPosition();

            positionArray.add(position);
        }

        //Create a set to remove all duplicate positions
        Set<String> noDuplicates = new HashSet<>();
        noDuplicates.addAll(positionArray);
        positionArray.clear();
        positionArray.addAll(noDuplicates);

        Log.d(LOGCAT, "Contested Offices and Candidates: " + positionArray.size() + " "+ candidateListSize);

        //Create the Contested Office according to the size of the position array
        //and make sure the names are added.
        int noOfContestedOffice = positionArray.size();

        for(int i = 0; i<noOfContestedOffice; i++)
        {
            office = new ContestedOffice(positionArray.get(i));
            Log.d(LOGCAT, "New Contested Office Created:" + office.getName());

            Candidate c = new Candidate();
            for(int j = 0; j < candidateListSize; j++)
            {
                //All the Seats/Position being Contested For
                String candidatePosition = candidateList.get(j).getPosition();
                String contestedOfficeName = office.getName();

                if(candidatePosition.equals(contestedOfficeName)) {
                    c = candidateList.get(j);
                    //Add the candidate to the Contested Office
                    office.add(c);
                }
                Log.d(LOGCAT, "Added Candidate: "+ candidateList.get(j) +" to: "+ office.getName());
            }
            //Add offices to ballot and ballot List
            ballot = new Ballot();
            ballot.add(office);

            //Ideally Ballot into BallotList
            ballotList.add(office);
            Log.d(LOGCAT, "Office definitely added to ballotList: " + ballotList.size());
        }
        return ballotList;
    }
}
```

**My VoteActivity XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activities.VoteActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/dashboard_vote_message"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:id="@+id/vote_message_placeholder"
            android:text="@string/vote_message" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    <include layout="@layout/fragment_ballot_layout"/>

    <include layout="@layout/footer_vote_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**RecyclerView XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/recycler_layout_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/vote_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**CardView XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/vote_candidate_image"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src = "@drawable/btn_ballot"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                tools:text="8.9"
                android:contentDescription="@string/candidate_photo" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/vote_candidate_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColorCandidateName"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    tools:text="CANDIDATE NAME" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/vote_candidate_party"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColorPartyDetails"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    tools:text="PARTY NAME" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/vote_candidate_details"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColorDetails"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    tools:text="Long placeholder for candidate details. 2 Lines Max" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_layout_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <!--Dynamic Checkboxes here-->

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zOFD.png)

Answer (score 0):

i think you are creating object of candidate every time in for loop make below chnages it will solve your problem

```
 Candidate c = new Candidate();
 ballot = new Ballot();
for(int i = 0; i<noOfContestedOffice; i++)
        {
            office = new ContestedOffice(positionArray.get(i));
            Log.d(LOGCAT, "New Contested Office Created:" + office.getName());


            for(int j = 0; j < candidateListSize; j++)
            {
                //All the Seats/Position being Contested For
                String candidatePosition = candidateList.get(j).getPosition();
                String contestedOfficeName = office.getName();

                if(candidatePosition.equals(contestedOfficeName)) {
                    c = candidateList.get(j);
                    //Add the candidate to the Contested Office
                    office.add(c);
                }
                Log.d(LOGCAT, "Added Candidate: "+ candidateList.get(j) +" to: "+ office.getName());
            }
            //Add offices to ballot and ballot List

            ballot.add(office);

            //Ideally Ballot into BallotList
            ballotList.add(office);
            Log.d(LOGCAT, "Office definitely added to ballotList: " + ballotList.size());
        }
```

just check it once and you are done with your problem.

i have update xml below

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/vote_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

check it out the height of recyclerview.

Comment: I still get the same output as the code I posted above.

Comment: post your xml here.

Comment: Editted question and added required XML

Comment: Still the same, the size of BallotList passed to the RecyclerAdapter when looped through is 15,1,15 which is accurate(3 ContestedOffices with varying sizes) but only the last element of each is being displayed.

Comment: there must be something wrong with xml,check all xml once.

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: bcz i have check the code there is nothing wrong with it,and you got all your data but there is a disply problem so,something in xml is wrong.

Comment: Gone through it, can't seem to find any issues, thanks for the help though.